# What is the difference between あっての and とあって?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles

From what I can tell they both mean "Because of", and the only differences in meaning I can see seem to be very subtle.

> **あっての:**
>
> - [Because of A (strong emphasis), B](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=402&PHPSESSID=9d0743b4d178eacc198e47143e66da41)
> - [Thanks to (various things), (outcome)](http://dev.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=atteno)
>
> **とあって:**
>
> - [Because of A, B](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=474&PHPSESSID=nwfllypu)
> - [Because ~; ~ as expected; because ~, naturally ~](http://dev.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=toatte)

As far as I can tell, the only difference is that `あっての` proceeds and follows a noun, while `とあって` can proceed and follow a sentence. Is there some other difference between these?

Comment: For posterity: since asking this question I've found another tricky one: にあって. Fortunately there is a big difference in meaning for this one; due to, during X time/situation, under the circumstances of _____

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, they are grammatically different. With あっての, both A and B have to be noun phrases, and the result is a noun phrase. With とあって, A can be a noun phrase or a clause, and B has to be a clause, the result being a clause.

Secondly, the focus is different. あっての emphasizes that B *could not be* without A, whereas this connection is weaker with とあって. With とあって, B tends to be the main point which the speaker is trying to get across, and A is added as extra explanation.