# meaning of ここに来て

Tags: grammar, meaning, idioms

> 「**ここに来て**の出費は痛いが、この状況を挽回するためにも、あの酒に頼らざるを得ん。背に腹は変えられないというが」

What does ここに来て mean in this context?

According to a definition I found on the internet

> ものがある段階でその性質や状態になったことを意味する表現

but, this isn't exactly clear to me.

Can anyone explain to me what nuance or meaning ここに来て adds? e.g. by explaining how the sentence would be different if you didn't include it.

Comment: Curious if it has to do with [this grammar](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-is-%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE-used-to-define-something)

Answer (score 6):

http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%81%93%E3%81%AB%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%A6

> thesaurus.weblio.jp
>
> 1. ここに到って ・ ここへ来て ・ ここまで来て ・ ここに至って ・ ここに来て ・ ここで ・ ここで初めて
> 2. 今さら ・ この期に及んで ・ こんな時に ・ 今の今になって ・ ここに来て ・ ここまで来て ・ せっかくここまで来たのに ・ 今更 ・ 今ごろになって

「ここに来ての出費は痛いが、この状況を挽回するためにも、あの酒に頼らざるを得ん。背に腹は変えられないというが」

Here, it's the 2nd meaning.  Similar to ここまで来て

"At this late stage"

"So late in the game ... "

ここに来て is usually like an adverb.

ここに来ての -- the last の here is there because it (ここに来ての) is modifying a noun 出費