# A question about 思っての愛のある

Tags: grammar, syntax, sentence

> あくまでその子のためを思っての愛のある行為でなくてはならず

This should mean something like: "it should be an an act of love putting the kid's interest in mind."
How does this 思っての愛のある行為 grammatically parse? Why is it ある行為 and not just 行為?

Comment: Isn't で or が missing before なくては?

Comment: indeed ,i fixed that

Answer (score 2):

There are two nested modifiers before 行為. It's parsed like:

> その子のためを思っての→(愛のある→行為)

You can interpret them separately.

1. その子のためを思っての行為 is "an act for the sake of the child", or more literally "an act that occurs by thinking about the benefit of the child". For this ての, see the following questions:

   - [Grammatical Pattern : VerbてのNoun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24709/5010)
   - [Trouble understanding this use of あっての](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8303/5010)
   - [How is あっての used to define something?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6504/5010)
2. 愛のある行為 "an act with love" or more literally "an act where love exists".