# Grammatical Pattern : VerbてのNoun

Tags: translation, syntax, て-form

What does this grammatical structure/pattern mean?

I am trying to understand the meaning of the following sentence where the VerbてのNoun pattern appears.

> "昭和64年に起きた誘拐事件を巡る物語だけに、“昭和な顔”を買われての起用だったという"

How do you translate the aforementioned sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 「Verb in [連用形]{れんようけい} + て + の + Noun」

is a phrase pattern in which the "Verb + て + の" part describes the condition that generates what is expressed by the following noun.

「“[昭和]{しょうわ}な[顔]{かお}”を[買]{か}われての[起用]{きよう}」 means:

**"casting based upon his reputation as having the 'Showa-esque face'"**

「買われる」 here means "to be regarded highly".

(I am not translating the whole sentence because you did not show us your attempt.)

I am sure some of you have come across the phrase 「[見]{み}てのお[楽]{たの}しみ」, which is in the same structure.  "You must see it to enjoy it!"

Comment: So is 〜あっての as in [this post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8303/78) just a singular example of this general `Verb in 連用形 + て + の + Noun` form?

Comment: Yes, it is.  That one is saying  "Being alive" is the prerequisite for mountain climbing.

Comment: Does the relative form 「買われる起用」 have the same meaning as 「買かわれての起用」?