# Usage of の following て-form in お申し込みにあたってのご注意

Tags: meaning, usage, particle-の

I read the answer to this question [Grammatical Pattern : VerbてのNoun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24709/grammatical-pattern-verb%e3%81%a6%e3%81%aenoun) but I do not see how it applies to the following sentence お申し込みにあたってのご注意

It cannot be "you must apply to be careful".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same idea still applies to your sentence (actually, it is not a complete sentence but a noun phrase).
It is "**notes on application**" of somewhat polite and formal form.

To find out this, you should carefully analyze your sentence.

As you know, the noun 「お申し込み」 is 「お」 + 「申し込み」, "application."

One of the basic meanings of the next verb 「あたる」  is "to face".

As described in the answer in the question you linked, 「-ての」 followed by nouns express the condition.
So 「お申し込みにあたっての」 is "*when* you face the application" or more naturally, "when you are making application."

Lastly, 「ご注意」 is 「ご」 + 「注意」.
Here this is a noun rather than a verb (注意する), so it should be "notes" or "precautions," but not "to be careful."

Now, the interpretation of whole phrase is, "notes when you are making application."

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I do not see it as a condition.  A condition is expressed by "if then" or "when then".  If it is translated  "notes when you are making the application", it looks more like a simultaneous event.

Comment: The word condition has 25 senses in http://www.dictionary.com/browse/condition.  If it is translated  "notes when you are making the application", it looks more like a "situation with respect to circumstances."  I'm afraid that labeling -ての as condition is very confusing.