# Metaphorical meaning of 買う

Tags: meaning, verbs, manga, metaphor

Context: in the manga [Rikudou](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6), Riku follows his trainer risky instructions in order to win (the trainer had told him to take a lot of punches in order to understand his opponent's fighting style). When, after risking his life, Riku is finally going to land a punch, his opponent thinks:

> 許す
>   打たせてやるよ
>   勝つために他人【セコンド】に自分の命全部投資出来る
>   お前の覚悟…
>   **買って**やる！！

What is the meaning of 買う in this case? My guess is that the opponent is envious of Riku's determination end wants to "acquire" it himself by letting him beat him. Is it correct?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhNs3.jpg) you can see the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Even though the mods seem to disagree, the particular meaning of 「買う」 has clearly been explained here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24709/grammatical-pattern-verb%e3%81%a6%e3%81%aenoun/24711#24711  「買われる」 is just the passive-voice form of 「買う」.

Comment: 向こうは質問の本題と違うところで補足的に触れられてるに過ぎないので、dupeとも言えないってことでreopenされたのかなと…時々あるパターンです。（個人的にはどっちでも良かったのですが、ある時点でreopen voteが3票だか入ってたのは見たので、個人の独断ではない民主的プロセスによるreopenだと思います）

Answer (score 6, accepted):

買う sometimes means "to appreciate (someone's trait)", "to value", etc. It has nothing to do with purchasing.

> #### [買う](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%86)
>
> 2. to value; to have a high opinion​
>      彼のスキーヤーとしての優秀性は十分に買っています。We fully appreciate his excellence as a skier.

> #### [買う](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/37318/meaning/m0u/%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%86/)
>
> ４ 価値を認める。「努力を―・う」

As is the case in your example, it's commonly used in decision-making contexts (e.g., やる気を買って彼を採用する, 難しい選択ですが彼の将来性を買いましょう). This お前の覚悟(を)買ってやる also implies the spaker made some decision (apparently "taking Riku's punches intentionally"?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you provide more details? I don't understand the relationship between valuing something/someone and decision-making.

Comment: @Marco ～を買う is perhaps along the lines of "to value ～ (as a basis of some decision related to person)" or sometimes even "to decide because of ～".

Answer (score -1):

[喧嘩]{けんか}を[売]{う}る means to pick or provoke a fight.

So, when you buy it, you take the challenge.

> 売られた喧嘩は決して買ってはいけないです。
>   You are by no means to accept the provocation (fight).

Comment: Are you saying that he is not completing his thought of "お前の覚悟..."? Because if he is, then an explanation of how 買う and 売る are used with 覚悟 would be helpful.

Comment: So.. does the 買う in 自分の命を投資できるお前の覚悟を**買っ**てやる have the same meaning as in 売られた喧嘩を**買う** ?